# The data is not being stored normally to mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

i have some problem.

the problem is data is not being stored normally to mongodb.

i don't know why does not work normally.

sources:

> write.ejs

```
<form method='post' action="/post/write">
    <table border="1">  
        <tr>
            <td>id</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='postid' id='postid'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>title</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='title' id='title'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>content</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='content' id='content'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="submit!">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>


</form>
```

> post.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    postid: String,
    title: String,
    content: String,
    published_date: { type: Date, default: Date.now}
})

postSchema.static.create = function (payload){
  // console.log('payload' + payload)
  // console.log('post' + post)
  const post = new this(payload)
  return post.save()
}

postSchema.statics.findAll = function (){
  return this.find({});
}

postSchema.statics.findOneByPostid = function (postid) {
  return this.findOne({ postid });
};

postSchema.statics.updateByPostid = function (postid, payload) {
  // { new: true }: return the modified document rather than the original. defaults to false
  return this.findOneAndUpdate({ postid }, payload, { new: true });
};

postSchema.statics.deleteByPostid = function (postid) {
  return this.remove({ postid });
};


module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema)
```

> post.js

```
const express = require('express')
const Post = require('../models/post')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express.Router()

app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  Post.findAll()
  .then((posts) => {
    if (!posts.length) return res.status(404).send({ err: 'post not found from get /'})
    res.render('posts', {data:posts})
  })
  .catch(err => res.status(500).send(err))
})

app.get('/postid/:postid', (req, res) => {
  Post.findOneByPostid(req.params.postid)
  .then((post) => {
    if (!post) return res.status(404).send({ err: 'post not found from get /postid:/postid '})
    // res.send(`findone successfully: ${post}`)
    res.render('post', {data:post})
  })
  .catch(err => res.status(500).send(err))
})

// this is example. it would be comment code.
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  Post.create(req.body)
  .then(post => res.send(post))
  .catch(err => res.status(500).send(err))
})

app.get('/write', (req, res) => {
  res.render('write')
})

app.post('/write', (req, res) => {
  console.log('req.body : ' + req.body)
  Post.create(req.body)
  .then(post => res.send(post))
  .catch(err => res.status(500).send(err))
})

app.put('/postid/:postid', (req, res) => {
  Post.updateByPostid(req.params.postid, req.body)
    .then(post => res.send(post))
    .catch(err => res.status(500).send(err));
});

app.delete('/postid/:postid', (req, res) => {
  Post.deleteByPostid(req.params.postid)
    .then(() => res.sendStatus(200))
    .catch(err => res.status(500).send(err));
});

module.exports = app
```

the problem is data is not being stored normally to mongodb.
when i send values at below route

http://localhost:3000/post/write

and results at the mongodb

```
{"_id":"5e038fd7d17c122ee084b397","published_date":"2019-12-25T16:35:35.566Z","__v":0}
```

supervisor app.js

```
> Starting child process with 'node app.js' Watching directory
> 'C:\workspace\my_blog' for changes. Press rs for restarting the
> process. (node:14860) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is
> deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new
> parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
> node server running successfully 3000 (node:14860) DeprecationWarning:
> current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will
> be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and
> Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the
> MongoClient constructor. Connected to mongod server 
> req.body : [object > Object]
```

req.body is  [object > Object] how can i see this object?

thank you

Comment: put console.logs to the post function in your express, so we can see what are that object and req.body 

`app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  Post.create(req.body)
  console.log(req.body)
  .then(post => {res.send(post), console.log(post)})
  .catch(err => res.status(500).send(err))
})`

Comment: Can you try to add `app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));`. For forms this needs to be added.

Comment: you need to do this : `console.log('req.body : ' + JSON.stringify(req.body))` to view in normal form. & then what was the issue with mongoDB updates ?

Comment: **Oner T.** thank you your help but req.body print out **req.body : [object Object]**

Comment: Thank you so much **Lokesh Daiya 7** that problem looks like fixed it! have a nice day

Comment: **srinivasy** thank you sooo much that issue is fixed it and i can see req.body thanks to your code! thank you all guys have a nice day happy new year :)